# Keen IO bulk add operation suddenly stops working

Tags: .net, keen-io

I’m starting to get this error message “One or more events was rejected during the bulk add operation” since July 3rd, every time I run my batch job to upload files from S3 to Keen using the [.net SDK](https://github.com/keenlabs/keen-sdk-net).

I'm not sure if this error is coming from Keen IO's server or somewhere else.

Do you have any idea why I’m getting this message?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the .NET SDK? It looks like your error messages is specific to that library.

Comment: Looking at the code in the SDK, this error will throw if you encounter any error in async upload. See https://github.com/keenlabs/keen-sdk-net/blob/master/Keen/KeenClient.cs#L320

Answer (score 4):

I have figured the root cause of the issue. Hopefully this can help others too.

I have one analytics envelop (AnalyticsEnvelope) which contains 20 activities (S3ToKeen.Activity). There are three of these activity objects (S3ToKeen.Activity) which contain a really long gibberish text (9241 chars each).

Someone (it can also be a bot because of the structure of the text) entered this text in one of our textbox. Our JavaScript captured and stored it in our analytics file in S3. To prevent, please put a limit on how many characters the user can enter in your website's textboxes.

It was hard to figure this out at the beginning, because we are sending the data in bulk of 100 item (S3ToKeen.AnalyticsItem). So I had to configure the batch job slightly and send the item one-by-one.

Answer (score 0):

That error is being thrown by the .net sdk because you hit some kind of API error during async upload. Is it possible for you to inspect which error that is being thrown by the Keen API? If you can get the detailed error response from the API, you can isolate the problem better. Here are the most common errors that you would encounter when posting an event:

1. Missing or invalid parameters. Error messages will often contain more information to help you figure out what’s wrong. Usually it's invalid JSON in one of your events.
2. Your request is too big. If your events have hundreds of properties and are unusually large, your batch might be too big to post. You can reduce the batch size to address this.

Some next steps for troubleshooting would be:

1. See if you can find the error message being thrown by the Keen API. It will have more detail about why the request failed.
2. Inspect your events to see if there are any obvious reasons why they would fail.

Comment: This is the only thing I can see in my log: Keen.Core.KeenBulkException: One or more events was rejected during the bulk add operation.

The exception doesn't give me any further information.